# Retinol — an oligomer of isoprene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

The following image is taken from [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Lipids/Isoprenoids)

[image: Retinol]

How does isoprene polymerise to form double bonds between two monomers and in each monomer? As far as I have learned is that upon polymerisation two monomer join by a single bond and form a double bond within each monomer which can be explained by the following image:

[image: isoprene polymer.]

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the Wikipedia page you linked to, you've got the answer to your own question.  It's not actually isoprene reacting with itself, but rather a more complicated pathway. The isoprene idea is just a convenient way of recognising terpenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Biomolecules that consist of ‘isoprene oligomers’ — more typically labelled *terpenes* do not actually polymerise in a way that you may be used to from plastic synthesis. When generating plastics, a double bond of a monomer unit (e.g. propene) is somehow made more reactive (e.g. by the addition of a nucleophile to generate an anion or by the addition of an electrophile to give a cation) and this reactive species then continues to attack monomer units giving a saturated chain of polypropylene.

Nature chooses a different path. It is not actually isoprene ((3*E*)-2-methylbut-1,3-diene) that is oligomerised — the resulting reaction would be far too hard for nature to control efficiently. Instead, the actually employed monomers are isopentenyl pyrophosphate (IPP) and dimethylallyl pyrophosphate (DMAPP).

[image: Isopentenyl pyrophosphate; IPP] [image: Dimethylallyl pyrophosphate; DMAPP]
**Figure 1:** The terpene biomonomers isopentenyl pyrophosphate (IPP; left or top) and dimethylallyl pyrophosphate (DMAPP; right or bottom).

As you can see, these only have one double bond but a diphosphate group attached to C4 that can be eliminated to give another. The biosynthetic pathway to couple these into oligomers begins by the removal of diphosphate from DMAPP resulting in a delocalised 3,3-dimethylallyl cation. This is captured by IPP’s terminal double bond to give a tertiary carbocation. In a final step, one of the two α-hydrogens in direction of former IPP’s diphosphate is eliminated to give geranyl pyrophosphate (figure 2).

[image: Geranyl pyrophosphate]
**Figure 2:** Geranyl pyrophosphate; the dimerisation product of IPP and DMAPP.

Another addition of IPP gives farnesyl pyrophosphate which is then fed into multiple different biosynthesis pathways.

Thus, terpenes can be considered *formal* oligomers of isoprene but one should never think that they are generated by *actual* condensation of isoprene units.